# Display different xsl:attribute depending on the ending of a string

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following xsl code in an xsl document

```
                <A target="_blank" style="text-decoration=none">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">viewdoc.aspx?doc=<xsl:value-of select="URLFilePath"/>&amp;mode=inline</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="prefix"><xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>: </xsl:attribute>
          <IMG src="images/word_small.gif" border="0"/>
                </A>
```

and in the code-behind I am doing this

```
            newItemNode = xmlDocument.CreateElement("URLFilePath")
            newItemNode.InnerText = correctedPath
            xmlItemNode.ParentNode.AppendChild(newItemNode)
```

Now that works fine for word documents.  However I need a way in code to check the extension of the file, and display the correct Image and xsl:attribute depending on the If statement.

So the If statement will be like this:-

```
            If correctedPath.ToLower.Contains(".doc") Then
                 //display the word icon and attributes
            Else
                 //display the excel icon and attributes
            End If
```

Can you please give me some tips and help on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a correct solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Just using `contains()` may generally produce the wrong results** (see the test XML document).

What is necessary is a [**`ends-with()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with) function, which is standard in XPath 2.0 and can be implemented in XSLT 1.0 as in the following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="URLFilePath">
   <xsl:variable name="visDoc">
    <xsl:call-template name="ends-with">
     <xsl:with-param name="pEnding" select="'.doc'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="visXls">
    <xsl:call-template name="ends-with">
     <xsl:with-param name="pEnding" select="'.xls'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$visDoc=1">word_small.gif</xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="$visXls=1">xls_small.gif</xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>unknown_small.gif</xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="ends-with">
   <xsl:param name="pEnding"/>

   <xsl:value-of select=
    "number(substring(.,
                      string-length() -string-length($pEnding) +1
                      )
    =
     $pEnding
            )
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following test XML document**:

```
<files>
 <URLFilePath>myFile.doc</URLFilePath>
 <URLFilePath>myFile.xls</URLFilePath>
 <URLFilePath>myFile.xls.doc</URLFilePath>
 <URLFilePath>myFile.doc.xls</URLFilePath>
</files>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
 word_small.gif
 xls_small.gif
 word_small.gif
 xls_small.gif
```

**Do note** that just using `contains()` produces incorrect results.

Comment: Hi Dimitre

At the moment I have 

     <A target="_blank" style="text-decoration=none">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">viewdoc.aspx?doc=<xsl:value-of select="URLFilePath"/>&amp;mode=inline</xsl:attribute>
      <i18n:popup key="results.open.word">
       <xsl:attribute name="prefix"><xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>: </xsl:attribute>

Comment: <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., '.doc')">
                  <IMG src="images/word_small.gif" border="0"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., '.xls')">
                  <IMG src="images/excel_small.gif" border="0"/>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
            </i18n:popup>
     </A>
and this seems to be working.  So how can I adapt to your example?

Comment: @Johann: This is *not* working with the XML document that I provided in my answer: `<files> <URLFilePath>myFile.doc</URLFilePath> <URLFilePath>myFile.xls</URLFilePath> <URLFilePath>myFile.xls.doc</URLFilePath> <URLFilePath>myFile.doc.xls</URLFilePath> </files>`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a solution! Sorry for the late reply but had to work on something else

Here is the code:-

```
                <A target="_blank" style="text-decoration=none">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., '.doc')">
              <xsl:attribute name="href">viewdoc.aspx?doc=<xsl:value-of select="URLFilePath"/>&amp;mode=inline
              </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="prefix">
                  <xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>:
                </xsl:attribute>
              <IMG src="images/word_small.gif" border="0"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., '.xls')">
              <xsl:attribute name="href">viewxls.aspx?doc=<xsl:value-of select="URLFilePath"/>&amp;mode=inline
              </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="prefix">
                  <xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>:
                </xsl:attribute>
              <IMG src="images/excel_small.gif" border="0"/>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
                </A>
```

Thanks for all your help guys, really very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A late reply but I hit to two answers that deal with matching end of string with XSLT 1.0 and are very elegant:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081205/520567
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081866/520567

go give them +1

Answer (score -2):

This can be done purely in your XSLT document if you require. For displaying the image, you could use a xsl:choose statement, that tests the URLFilePath element

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains(., '.doc')">
      <IMG src="images/word_small.gif" border="0"/> 
   </xsl:when> 
   <xsl:when test="contains(., '.xls')">
      <IMG src="images/excel_small.gif" border="0"/> 
   </xsl:when> 
</xsl:choose>
```

If you wanted to do this check in the code behind, you could always add extra attributes to your URLFilePath element.

```
imageAttr = xmlDocument.CreateAttr("image")     
If correctedPath.ToLower.Contains(".doc") Then
    imageAttr.value = "images/word_small.gif"
Else
    imageAttr.value = "images/excel_small.gif"
End If
newItemNode.AppendChild(imageAttr)
```

And then, in your xls, you can simply use this attribute to set the source attribute of the image

```
<IMG border="0"> 
   <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select='@image' /></xsl:attribute>
</IMG>
```

Comment: Hi Tim

Thanks a lot for your help

Would something like this work also?

Comment: <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains(., '.doc')">
<A target="_blank" style="text-decoration=none">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">viewdoc.aspx?doc=<xsl:value-of select="URLFilePath"/>&amp;mode=inline</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="prefix"><xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>: </xsl:attribute>
          <IMG src="images/word_small.gif" border="0"/>
                </A>
   </xsl:when>

Comment: <xsl:when test="contains(., '.xls')">
<A target="_blank" style="text-decoration=none">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">viewxls.aspx?doc=<xsl:value-of select="URLFilePath"/>&amp;mode=inline</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="prefix"><xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>: </xsl:attribute>
          <IMG src="images/excel_small.gif" border="0"/>
                </A>
   </xsl:when> 
</xsl:choose>

Comment: Hi Johann. Yep, something like that would work. You can next any amount of elements within the xsl:when. You should try and avoid repeating code though, are use the xsl:choose for only the bits that differ, if you can.

Comment: `contains` only checks whether the substring occurs anywhere in the target string, not whether it appears at the *end* of the target string.