# Regular Expressions in xsl:template match attribute

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xpath

I just want to know if it's possible to use regular expressions in the `match` attribute of the `xsl:template` element.
For example, suppose I have the follow XML document:

```
<greeting>
    <aaa>Hello</aaa>
    <bbb>Good</bbb>
    <ccc>Excellent</ccc>
    <dddline>Line</dddline>
</greeting>
```

Now the XSLT to transform the above document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="matches(node-name(*),'line')">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to use the syntax `matches(node-name(*),'line$')` in the `match` attribute of the `xsl:template` element, it retrieves a error message. Can I use regular expressions in the `match` attribute?

Thanks very much

Comment: Next time, please just read the box beside the text box, where it says *"How to format: indent code by 4 spaces"*. Then you don't have to use `&lt;` etc...

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer, which at this time contains the only completely correct solution to your two related questions. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Here is the correct XSLT 1.0 way of matching** (in XSLT 2.0 use the matches() function with a real RegEx as the `pattern` argument):

**Matching an element whose name contains `'line'`**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'line')]"> 
  <!-- Whatever processing is necessary --> 
</xsl:template>
```

**Matching an element whose name ends in `'line'`**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[substring(name(), string-length() -3) = 'line']"> 
  <!-- Whatever processing is necessary --> 
</xsl:template>
```

*@Tomalak* provided another XSLT 1.0 way of finding names that end with a given string. His solution uses a special character that is guaranteed not to be ever present in any name. My solution can be applied to find if any string (not only a name of an element) ends with another given string.

**In XSLT 2.x** :

**Use**: `matches(name(), '.*line$')` to match names that end with the string `"line"`

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[matches(name(), '.*line$')]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(matches(name(), '.*line$'))]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::text())]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the XML document**:

```
<greeting>
    <aaa>Hello</aaa>
    <bblineb>Good</bblineb>
    <ccc>Excellent</ccc>
    <dddline>Line</dddline>
</greeting>
```

**Copies to the output only the element, whose name ends with the string `"line"`**:

```
<dddline>Line</dddline>
```

**While this transformation** (uses `matches(name(), '.*line')` ):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[matches(name(), '.*line')]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(matches(name(), '.*line'))]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::text())]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**copies to the output all elements, whose names contain the string `"line"`:**

```
<bblineb>Good</bblineb>
<dddline>Line</dddline>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks very much by your effort, it was the first time i post a doubt in this forum i am realy surprise of fast you had respond.I miss the version of the xslt that i pretend to work with, it will be 2.0 and yes i want to find the string 'line' at the of a string.
One more time thnaks very much by your support

Comment: @pedromarquescosta: You are welcome. I have updated my answer with the requested XSLT 2.0 solution that uses RegEx.

Comment: Is part of this answer missing. I.e.  the bit for XSLT 2.0 after "This transformation:". What transformation??

Comment: @spinkus, Thanks for reporting this -- I don't know how the transformation lost its formatting as "code". Now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

In XSLT 1.0 (and 2.0, too), for your example (it's not a regex, though):

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'line')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

and to achieve an end-of-string match:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(concat(name(), '&#xA;'), 'line&#xA;')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 2.0 you can of course use the `matches()` function in place of `contains()`.

Comment: @Dimitre: As you said, LF can't be part of the `name()`. So if you can't use XPath 2.0 (and regex), this would be a way of matching a name that contains the string `'line'` at its end, instead of anywhere. The OP seems to want that, because he mentions the regex `'line$'`, and he did not indicate the XSLT version he uses. I could have used space, or any other character that is illegal in names. So it's not at all meaningless or incorrect. ;-)